# How do I rewrite a URI to a destination with a query string

Tags: java, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We are trying to redirect bin-ends2 to wines.jsp with a number of parameters passed over to the application server. Apache is stripping the parameters off and so the application server fdoes not know what yo put in the page. The Apache config is:

```
RewriteRule ^/wines/bin-ends2$ http://qa2:7025/wines/wines.jsp?Form=WinesSearch&type=binends [PT]
```

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `QSA` flag to your rule when you introduce new query string parameters and would like to preserve (better say, include) existing query string.

Your rule should be

```
RewriteRule ^/wines/bin-ends2$ http://qa2:7025/wines/wines.jsp?Form=WinesSearch&type=binends [QSA,PT]
```

Useful link: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have done this with all possible combinations of QSA, PT, R and L but none of them work. I'm going to strip out the rest of the config just in case there is something conflicting with this rewrite.